# Creating plsql function for Factorial program

Tags: plsql

When I call the function using select statement
[select fact(5) from dual;]
I get output as 1.Can you guys please help me from the below code

```
create or replace function fact(num in number)

return number

Is 

res_fact number:=1;

begin

for i in 1..5 loop

res_fact:=res_fact*i;

 dbms_output.put_line(res_fact);

 -- dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of '||num||' = '||res_fact);

 return res_fact;

 end loop;

 dbms_output.put_line(res_fact);

 end;

 res_fact=res_fact*i;
 as i call function i used to get the factorial of that input number
 res_fact=5*4*3*2*1;
 res_fact=120
```

Comment: This seems like homework, so I won't give a direct answer but some hints: What's the argument `num` supposed to do? What do you want to return and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this code "return res_fact;" out of loop you code will run, But above code work for only 5.

Comment: I wants to execute function using plsql statements                                                                   
                                                                                                                           
declare 
v_fact number;                                                                                                                              
begin
                                                                                                                                  v_fact:=fact(8);  
dbms_output.put_line(v_fact);
end;

Comment: @zealcollege you have created a function wherever you want use even procedure or select statement

Comment: Can u gave me ur gmail id plz

Comment: @Zealcollege Is there any more issue your are facing..kkr13590@gmail.com

Comment: need to talk to you on hangout

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.... 
Firstly you need to move your return statement outside of your loop.  As you now have it it will return on the first pass through the loop.

Secondly you are ignoring your input parameter and always going to get factorial of 5 rather than what is passed in (once you move your return statement.

See code below

```
create or replace function fact(num in number)
return number
Is 
  res_fact number:=1;
begin
  for i in 1..num loop
    res_fact:=res_fact*i;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of '||num||' = '||res_fact);
  return res_fact;
end;
```